# Delete observations for regression modelling

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, dataset, robust

I am implementing robust regression on some data and when i tested the accuracy on a hold set of data, the accuracy was very bad. I have about 500 000 observations for the regression model and I deleted about 20% of the observations in such a way that each observation should include at least 3 of the 10 independent variables. What I realized, if I delete the observations this way I can improve my accuracy a lot. The significance of the variables also stays the same whether I delete the observations or not and the hold out data set contains observations that only has one or two of the independent variables.

But I would like to know whether there is a formal method for deleting observations?

Comment: so you deleted those observations that had less than 3 of the 10 IV?

Comment: Yes i deleted observations with less than 3 IV.

Comment: It looks like what you are doing is multivariate regression. I would the appropriate tag if I could, but I have no permission to do so. I am quite puzzled by what you wrote: the dependent variable depends on a variable number of independent variables? How is it so? Could you please clarify on the use of the terminology accuracy and significance in this context?

Comment: @JasonSamuels: do you have any guess as to what mechanism removed these missing cells in your design matrix? For example are the cells missing at random (in the terminology of [Rubin 1976](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/trg/papers/rubin-missing-76.pdf))?

Comment: I am using R and the package robustbase with lmrob to do my regression modelling. The results also gives me the significance of the variables regarding the model (t-values). The accuracy is the comparison between the actuals and forecasted values for the hold out data. The data is not really missing some obeservations just does not contain all the independent variables.